Struggling to create Oval shaped circle/area in Ansys APDL

I scrating head for several hours, and tried finding suitable videos to learn creating oval shaped circle in ansys. Most of the tutorials use geometry modeler, I want to use APDL only, where I don't find ellipse option. Can anyone guide me as to how I can create oval shaped circle in ansys. It is for the area NOT volume. I am using 2024 APDL version for the student.
